# on the fly editing of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to allow users to log into the site and when they click a specific element, that element will change to an input text field and then allow the user to type whatever they wish into there.

However, once I click the inout field it keeps adding more code for another input field. Does this make sense?

Here is my jQuery:

```
$('.editTagline').click(function() {
  var content = $(this).html();
  $(this).html('<input type="text" value="' +content+ '">');    
});
```

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nSY4Y/ if you click the word tagline and then try to enter text into the input text field you will see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `one()`, that way it only works once for each element

```
$('.editTagline').one('click', function () {
    var content = $(this).html();
    $(this).html('<input type="text" value="' + content + '">');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nSY4Y/3/)

Comment: Of course, doh! Thank you. I will accept the answer after the ten mins requirement has passed :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/):

```
$('.editTagline').on('click', function () {
    var content = $(this).html();
    $(this).html('<input type="text" value="' + content + '">');
    $(this).off('click');
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nSY4Y/5/)

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the class once the content is replaced:

```
$(document).on("click", ".editTagline", function() {
  var content = $(this).html();
  $(this).html('<input type="text" value="">');
  $(this).find("input").val(content);
  $(this).removeClass("editTagline");
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robbyn/9q9BQ/1/)